# Create A4 size PDF from image by using reportlab

Tags: python, image, pdf, reportlab

I want to convert an A4 scanned image to PDF by using reportlab in python. I wrote bellow code but I get error. How can I fix it ?

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
height, width = A4
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("image.pdf", pagesize=A4)
parts = []
parts.append(Image("image.jpg",width=210*mm, height= 293*mm))
doc.build(parts)
```

reportlab.platypus.doctemplate.LayoutError: Flowable (595.275590551 x 830.551181102) too large on page 2 in frame 'normal'(439.275590551 x 685.88976378*) of template 'Later'

Comment: You can tell reportlab to resize the image, or you can not use a document with margins where the image won't fit.  Or if you really just need a PDF version of the image, try img2pdf.py

Answer (score 0):

```
parts.append(Image("image.jpg",width=210*mm-doc.rightMargin-doc.leftMargin, height=293*mm-doc.topMargin-doc.bottomMargin))
```

should work. if you need to keep the aspect ratio of image.jpg, you will need a little more additional work.